# What are good beginner circuit simulator programs?

Tags: circuit-design, simulation

I am a software engineer and, as a hobby, I have been trying to learn more about building electronic circuits and making use of microcontrollers for making items such as robots.

I know the basics of circuit design, but I would like to do more experimentation on the computer before physically building my circuits. I've glanced around at some circuit simulator programs, but they seem complicated to me. What are some good beginner programs that will allow me to design and test circuits?

Thanks!

Comment: Google "LT Spice".  It's free and awesome.

Comment: Isis/Proteus is a good start. It's not free but should have Student or Light version. It has a wide range of libraries and also it allows you to simulate MCUs. NOTE: Not an advertisement.

Comment: You may use proteus ..... I have personally worked with proteus and it enables the user to simulate wireless transmission circuits as well....For example you may transmit signal using zigbee or bluetooth . In that case if you want to see if the modes you selected for your microcontroller works or not....then you may see that simulation in proteus.

Comment: i find that http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html is free and online and has a good amount of complexity for hobbyists. it's just for circuits (no pcb help), but its a simple and easy sim for testing/planning/debugging, and has a good number of common components

Comment: I second @dandavis, that software is by far **the best**. It's much better than what this site recommends when trying to make a schematic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to http://www.linear.com and download the free LT-Spice software. It works really well after you get used to the schematic drawing GUI in the program.

[image]